# How do I query with a where clause on a has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

For example:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::base
  has_one :group, through: :users
end
```

I want to query something like `Request.where(user_id: nil)` but it's complaining that requests.user_id does not exist.

Thanks!

EDIT:
A coworker help me and I got it to work. Here is the query:

```
Request.joins(:user).where('users.group_id is null')
```

My understanding is that you have to join the user since the group id is from the users table and then use a string for the where clause.

Comment: Do you have the user_id property in Request model? Also, please provide the code for User model as well as Group.

Comment: You haven't provided enough info for us to help you. Can you go to the rails console and try: `Request.where(user_id: nil).to_sql` and show us the results? (add it to your question... code formatting in comments is awful)

Comment: Thank you but I figure it out from the help of a coworker